# angularjs $http.post with parameters

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new at angular and if my question is kinda low lvl dont be angry with me.

I have web service which returns sessionId and login success message if user will pass auth. for example url is that:

> http://localhost:8181/login?username=USERNAME&password=12345

and here's my response:

```
{"sessionId":"0997cec2a8b34c84ba8419ab1204e6aa","loginSucceeded":true}
```

here's my login controller:

```
app.controller('loginCtrl', function($scope, loginService){
    $scope.login=function(user){
        loginService.login(user);
    }
});
```

and here's my service:

```
app.factory('loginService', function($http){
    return{
        login: function(user){
            var $promise=$http.post('http://localhost:8181/login?', user);
            $promise.then(function(msg){
                if(msg.loginSucceeded=="true")
                    console.log("opa")
                else
                    console.log("den");
            });
        }
    }
});
```

and I have user.username and user.password in my scope (using textboxes).

How can I pass those parameters in url and how can I parse that response?

Comment: you can just append them to the url using string concatenation.

Comment: @toskv ok understood it. and what about parse response?

Comment: usually the response has a **data** field with the already parsed information the server sent (assuming the server responds with JSON or a string).

Comment: you can concatenate them as string, or passing them as an object as the second parameter in the $http.post, if you have REST controllers in the backend

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your code you're passing the username and password in the URL of the POST request. If that's what you really want (it's more common to pass them as POST data) than you can use this:

```
login: function(user){
    var url = 'http://localhost:8181/login?username=' + user.name + '&password=' + user.password;
    $http.post(url).then(function(msg){
        if(msg.loginSucceeded==="true"){
            console.log("opa")
        }else{
            console.log("den");
        }
    });    
}
```

If you want to pass the data as POST data, you can pass that as the second argument in the `$http.post()` call:

```
login: function(user){
    var url = 'http://localhost:8181/login';
    var data = {username: user.name, password: user.password};
    $http.post(url, data).then(function(msg){
        if(msg.loginSucceeded==="true"){
            console.log("opa")
        }else{
            console.log("den");
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: thanks but it throws an exception "ReferenceError: $scope is not defined"

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question a bit. I saw: I have user.username and user.password in my scope, so I was using the scope directly. I didn't see you were using a service to do the call. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I never seen anyone passing login data via query string, 
if you are in simple http protocol... you should consider using [Basic Access Authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) or [oAuth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth)...

by the way, if you need to do what described above... this could be help you!

```js
angular
  .module('test', [])
  .service('LoginService', function($q, $http) {
    var self = this;
  
    self.login = function(username, password) {
      var configs = { cache: false };
      var payload = {
        "username" : username,
        "password" : password
      };
      
      // The Method Post is generally used with a payload, but if you need to pass it as query string... you have to do:
      configs.params = payload;
      return $http
        .post('/api/login', null /* but normally payload */, configs)
        .then(function(result) { 
          console.log('LoginService.login:success', result); 
          return result.data;
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.log('LoginService.login:error', error);
          return $q.reject(error);
        });
      ;
    };
  })
  .controller('LoginCtrl', function(LoginService, $scope) {
    var vm = $scope
    vm.username = 'hitmands';
    vm.password = 'helloWorld';
    vm.debug = 'CIAO';
  
    vm.onFormSubmit = function(event, form) {
      if(form.$invalid) {
        event.preventDefault();
        return;
      }
      
      vm.debug = null;
      
      return LoginService
      .login(vm.username, vm.password)
      .then(function(data) { vm.debug = data; })
      .catch(function(error) { vm.debug = error; })
    ;
      
    };
  })
;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<article ng-app="test">
  <div ng-controller="LoginCtrl">
    <form ng-submit="onFormSubmit($event, loginForm);" name="loginForm">
      <input type="text" placeholder="username" ng-model="username">
      <input type="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="password">
      <div>
        <button type="submit">Send Login Data</button>
      </div>
      
      <div style="color: blue; padding: 1em .5em;" ng-bind="debug | json">
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</article>
```