# Angularjs post login request unable to request login

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, post, authentication

I am unable to request login authentication from URL via payload in AngularJS

Code below works just fine,

```
$http({
    method: 'POST', 
    url: URL + '&user=' + $scope.vModel.username + '&password=' + $scope.vModel.password,
    headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' }
})
.then(function(response){})
```

However since passing user credentials in URL is not a good practice I checked: [angularjs $http.post with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33355497/angularjs-http-post-with-parameters)

But my code for the same authenticate URL is not working as per below code:

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: {
        user: $scope.vModel.username,
        password: $scope.vModel.password
    },
    headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' }
})
.then(function(response){})
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What are you getting, error?

Comment: Did you check is your service working properly for post method? you can use postman check your service

Comment: Nothing wrong in the angular code. Second example may not be working because end-point is not configured properly.

Comment: 401 (Unauthorized) its saying user and password are wrong but it is actually not

Comment: If end-point is configured to take request payload, it should work

Comment: Yes. it should work. Check ur endpoint.

Comment: @Lakmi Postman can only add headers to http requests, is there anyway to add request payload as well?

Comment: @SanjaySingh you can add request payload into postman.

Comment: @SanjaySingh in postman you can set POST request then enable body there you can code your json

Answer (score 0):

You have a request with Access-Control-Allow-Origin but you did not check that your service is working properly and/or this service allows your request.

Comment: Checked with Cyber Security Team they have other service opening another web page which can be used to enter username and password to get session token, only problem is I don't know if can write the code to catch response from other pages

Answer (score 0):

After Escalating to cyber security I finally got the answer
This endpoint service can be used by their web page which accepts input username and password and gives a session token in response which then can be used to access data from servers.

Now I need to figure out if my angular code can catch the response from their web page so that I can get session token